# Is it possible to make a thread / task use http proxy for all connections inside

Tags: c#, proxy, network-programming, task, smtpclient

Alright let me try to explain what i am asking as much as possible

When you start a task like below

```
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
     {
         myFunction();
     });
```

I want all network operations inside `myFunction` to use `http proxy`. Is this possible ?

It is possible to use proxy for `httpwebrequest` class but for example when i am sending mail with using yahoo smtp i am not able to use any proxy.

So think it like inside this, always no matter what use this proxy for all network operations

C# 4.5

Ok this is how i send email with yahoo smtp. Now yahoo smtp itself is a proxy. But i want to use another proxy (http web proxy) while connecting yahoo smtp in this case.

Is this possible ?

```
 public static bool func_SendEmail(string srFrom, string srSenderEmail, string srSenderEmailPw,
        string srHtmlBody, string srTextBody, string srTitle, string srProxy, string srSentToEmail)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(new MailAddress(srSenderEmail, srFrom), new MailAddress(srSentToEmail)))
            using (AlternateView textPart = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(srTextBody, Encoding.UTF8, "text/plain"))
            using (AlternateView htmlPart = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(srHtmlBody, Encoding.UTF8, "text/html"))
            {
                message.ReplyTo = new MailAddress(srSenderEmail, srFrom);
                message.IsBodyHtml = false;
                message.Subject = srTitle;
                message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                textPart.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;
                message.AlternateViews.Add(textPart);
                htmlPart.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.QuotedPrintable;
                message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlPart);
                message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
                using (SmtpClient oSmtp = new SmtpClient())
                {

                    oSmtp.Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";
                    oSmtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(srSenderEmail, srSenderEmailPw);
                    oSmtp.EnableSsl = false;
                    oSmtp.Port = 587;
                    oSmtp.Send(message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception E)
        {
            lock (swErrors)
            {
                swErrors.WriteLine(E.Message.ToString());
                if (E.InnerException != null)
                {
                    swErrors.WriteLine(E.InnerException.ToString());
                }
                swErrors.WriteLine("");
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Use a different SMTP client?

Comment: How are you setting/configuring the proxy?

Comment: @ErickT it is not possible to setup proxy when using yahoo smtp.

Comment: @Paul can you explain more ? i am using yahoo smtp and c# 4.5 SmtpClient

Comment: How about a passing your proxy as a state object: `public Task StartNew(Action<Object> action,Object state)`? Shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321456.aspx